# Why are anti bonding orbitals distorted towards the less electronegative element?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

Bonding molecular orbitals are distorted towards the more electronegative atom and so the atomic orbitals from this atom contribute more to those bonding orbitals. This implies that anti bonding molecular orbitals are distorted in the same way towards the more electropositive atom. In the case of bonding molecular orbitals being distorted, the reason for the distortion is intuitively that electrons are attracted to the more electronegative atom and so are closer in energy, but it is not intuitive to me for the anti bonding orbitals why the more electropositive atom is the one which attracts the anti bonding electrons to a greater extent - they are still electrons after all so why should the more electropositive atom distort their electron density towards it?

Comment: It could be that electrons in antibonding orbitals are repelled from the higher electron density in the bonding orbitals that is higher in the vicinity of the more electronegative atom.  In effect antibonding electrons force the atoms apart weakening bonds so are not as strongly attracted to both atoms.

Comment: If that is not intuitive, why just above  you said "it implies"? Because of the reason explained by Hans Wurst? If so, we are at the starting point....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant atomic orbitals of an electronegative element are typically lower in energy than the relevant atomic orbitals on the element with lower electronegativity.

This means that the bonding molecular orbital, which is the molecular orbital with low energy, should include a higher coefficient of the atomic orbital that is lower in energy, i.e. the atomic orbital of the electronegative element. The coefficient of an atomic orbital over all molecular orbitals has to sum to 1. Which means that you can't mix as much into the antibonding molecular orbital and you have to use more of the atomic orbital of the more electro-positive element atomic orbital in the antibonding molecular orbital construction. This means that the bonding molecular orbital is "dominated" by the atomic orbital of the electronegative element, while the antibonding molecular orbital is "dominated" by the atomic orbital of the less electronegative element. Leading to the observation that the bonding molecular orbitals is distorted towards the more electronegative element, while the antibonding molecular orbital is distorted towards the other element.